# Not able to insert data in Mongodb using MQTT

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save the data from MQTT broker into Mongodb. Using the following code:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt'); //includes mqtt server 
var mongodb = require('mongodb'); // includes mongoDB 
var mongodbClient = mongodb.MongoClient; //initialises the mongoDB client
var mongodbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/WheelSenseHat'; 
var deviceRoot = "iot-lab/wheel/sensehat/"; 
var collection,client; 

mongodbClient.connect(mongodbURI, setupCollection);

function setupCollection(err, db) {
   if(err) 
throw err;
   collection=db.collection("WheelData"); 
   client=mqtt.connect({ host: 'iot.eclipse.org', port: 1883 }); 
   client.subscribe(deviceRoot+"+"); //subscribing to the topic name 
   client.on('message', insertEvent); //inserting the event

}

//function that displays the data in the MongoDataBase
function insertEvent(topic,message) {
   var key=topic.replace(deviceRoot,'');
   collection.update(
   { _id:key }, 
   { $push: { events: { event: {  value:message, when:new Date() } } } }, 
   { upsert:true },

   function(err,docs) {  
   if(err) {
      console.log("Insert fail")// Improve error handling       
     }
 }

 );

}
```

but the data is not getting saved in MongoDB. Output shown below:

> show dbs
>   admin  0.000GB
>   local  0.000GB
>   use WheelSenseHat
>   switched to db WheelSenseHat
>   show collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your program even receiving the MQTT message?  Try putting a `console.log(topic + ":" + message)` into your `insertEvent()` function to see if it's even being called.  Your subscribe translates to `iot-lab/wheel/sensehat/+`, which will match MQTT messages like `iot-lab/wheel/sensehat/data1`, but not `iot-lab/wheel/sensehat/sensor/data`...the '+' only matches one 'level' while a '#' will match anything. If your incoming MQTT messages have more than one level past 'sensehat', then your program won't receive any messages....and thus, no records in your database.